# how to access same directory file in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have facing a problem is when **the url is** `http://localhost/admin/add_department/11` then I clicked a button which under same folder and will go to **general_setting.php** but **the url will became** `http://localhost/admin/add_department/general_setting` and **still at add_department page** ,
**I want it became** `http://localhost/admin/general_setting`,

this is my current **.htaccess** file content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(admin)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ test/application/$1/$2.php?action=edit&department_id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(admin)/([\w-]+) test/application/$1/$2.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

`http://localhost/admin/general_setting` is work under my current **.htaccess** file,
how to redirect `http://localhost/admin/add_department/11` to `http://localhost/admin/general_setting`
thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Only the server knows your folder structure. So if you want to go from `http://localhost/admin/add_department/11` to `http://localhost/admin/general_setting` you should make your link point to `../general_setting` instead of just 'general_setting'.

**Update**

A second option is to make all URLs relative to the domain. So if you want to go to `http://localhost/admin/add_department/11`. You make the link `/admin/add_department/11` and if you want to go to `http://localhost/admin/general_setting` you make the link `/admin/general_setting`. The slash on the beginning means that it has to look from the domain you're on.

You might have to set a base tag depending on your situation.

```
<base href="http://localhost">
```

[Documentation of base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Comment: yes i know, but there are a menu bar 
let said i have **2 button** on my menu bar
one is **general_setting** and another is **add_department**
if i write `../general_setting`, url will became `http://localhost/admin/general_setting ` but if i clicked `../general_setting` **again** url will became `http://localhost/general_setting `

Comment: @ReiTee I see your point. I updated my answer with a solution

Comment: Hi, i have try just now, i add `<base href="http://localhost/admin">` and its not so suitable for my situation because my menu is like:
 _Menu_ **Setting**  `href:#`
_Sub-Menu_ **==>General Setting**  `href:general_setting` 
i clicked **Setting** the _Sub-Menu_ only will **expand**,but when i clicked **Setting** the url will became `http://localhost/admin/#` and consider **Object not found!**